# Rollback of conda environment results in CondaUpgradeError

Tags: anaconda, conda

```
CondaUpgradeError: This environment has previously been operated on by a conda version that's newer
than the conda currently being used. A newer version of conda is required.
  target environment location: C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3
  current conda version: 4.5.11
  minimum conda version: 4.6
```

Ok, let's try something stupid...

```
C:\Users\XXXXXXXX>pip install conda==4.6
Collecting conda==4.6
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement conda==4.6 (from versions: 3.0.6, 3.5.0, 3.7.0, 3.17.0, 4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.0.3, 4.0.4, 4.0.5, 4.0.7, 4.0.8, 4.0.9, 4.1.2, 4.1.6, 4.2.6, 4.2.7, 4.3.13, 4.3.16)
No matching distribution found for conda==4.6
```

How do I get out of this trap? I've tried to upgrade it with various conda install and conda update commands but nothing works. This apparently happened upgrading from 4.6 to 4.6.2

Comment: Please don't flag this as answered elsewhere - I've reviewed those and they do not have an answer for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Its a bug. recommendations are posted [here](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/conda/GbVfDSL8eU8) on the conda issue board

basically, reinstall from cache or downgrade, then upgrade conda